# Vectorizing a double sum with j < i+1

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to calculate a double sum, which now I'm doing in a double for loop as follows:

```
k = 3

sumterm = 0.0
for i in range(k):
    for j in range(i+1):
        sumterm = i+2*j
```

I would like to vectorize this sum, though what I'm stuck on is, I'm not just summing every combination of i and j, but just of j < i+1. How would I vectorize this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you provide the actual summation?

Comment: Sure! I updated the post.

Comment: Assuming that you have your data in a matrix `A(i,j)`, you just want to zero out the entries that do not comply with your criterion (ie `j<i+1`) and then take each row as a vector and add all of the rows.

Comment: You can/ should precompute the values of `sm` and `sk` for different values of `m`/`k`

Comment: There is still another function missing: `mpf()`. Can you please post a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including example data?

Comment: The mpf() is from from mpmath import *.  I realy appreciate you guys being so invested, though my question was just how to vectorize the double loop in the first piece of code. The two functions in the bottom code are just to satisfy Olivier's curiosity. I hope with your help vectorizing the first double for loop I will be able to get the actual functions running faster (no guarantee, though).

Comment: The double loop you want help with, `sumterm`  is always `k+(2*k)`.  Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right! I changed the range of i to k.

Comment: Isn't there a closed-form formula for this summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is sum a function `func` over a triangular `k * k` matrix. Here is the way to do it with your for loops which I slightly modified to fit our abstraction.

```
k = 3

summation = 0.0
for i in range(k + 1): # Loop from 0 to k
    for j in range(i + 1): # Loop from 0 to i
        summation += func(i, j) # Sum the value
```

You can vectorize your summation by abstracting the matrix with `itertools.product` instead of loops.

```
from itertools import product

summation = sum(func(i, j) for i, j in product(range(k + 1), repeat=2) if j <= i)
```

The function `product` returns an iterator, which is memory efficient, especially if you need `k` to be big.